# Apache tomcat proxy configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, port

I am running IIS on port 80, I configured Apache on port 8080, while I am accessing my Apache server, I can't access without typing the port, such as:

> http://mywebsite.co.in:8080/main

But i want to access like:

> http://mywebsite.co.in/page

How do I hide or remove port in my `url`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the port in your url because you are running your webserver (Apache) on a non-standard port.  So, to eliminate this, you need to run Apache on port 80, which is the default `http` port, and what's assumed by the browser if no port is given.

So, your options are:

1. Get a new server for Apache
2. Move Apache to port 80, and move/delete IIS
3. Put up with needing the port in the url